# How to add stroke paint into difference tool in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

Basically, Inkscape is not adding my stroke paint into the final result when I use the Difference tool. Same thing for the Exclusion tool. I can't just change the size of what I need to be a difference because it's text, converted to a path, ungrouped, and put into a union. Here a picture to demonstrate what I mean:
[image: TheProblem]

So, how do I fix this? Is there a workaround that I don't know about or am I missing something silly?

Comment: I hope you are using that font only for demonstration.

Comment: Not only for demonstration purposes but also to tease everybody on this site. I hate it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select your text.
2. *Path → object to path.*
3. *Ungroup.*
4. *Path → stroke to path.*
5. Remove all inner paths. You can do this by *breaking apart* everything and remove all parts except the outermost ones and the [counters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_(typography)) and then *combine* what is left.

Comment: By "remove all inner paths" do you mean just delete all of the inside nodes? Or is there a faster way to do this than just dragging over them with the node tool and repeatedly pressing the delete key?

Comment: @Scratchifier- You can use Path- Break Apart instead of deleting individual nodes. (For letters where you have a hollow space in the middle this command clubs entirely, in which case you need to use Path-Difference to obtain the hollow space)

Comment: @chanduc: You could also just combine again instead of using *difference.* I expanded my answer on this.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Thanks, I didn't try this before. Looks like this is more convenient than the difference method. But this method only works when even-odd fill rule is selected.